# Pre-commit hook for git to play sound clip

Tags: macos, git

I need a precommit hook that will play a sound clip (Specifically "Push It" by Salt-n-Pepa) Any thoughts on how I can get this done?

Comment: The answer to this depends on the platform you're running Git on.

Comment: This is a valid question. Lots of good habit stuff, especially in CI, depends on fun things like this!

Comment: Mac user here. Thanks :)

Comment: Exactly what I wanted to do!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are on OS X 10.5 or later, you can use the [`afplay`](http://www.macworld.com/article/1138554/105audioterm.html) utility from a pre-commit hook to accomplish exactly this.

Comment: Suggestions on how I can implement that with my precommit hook?

Comment: Uhm, not sure what you are asking.  Pass the filename you want to play.  For example, put this in your script and adjust the path: `afplay "/path/to/song.mp3"`

Answer (score 1):

Not sure which sound player you are using, but you need to use the command `start` to launch non-console apps.

For example, to launch a VisualStudio solution you can do this from MSysGit (I'm assuming you are on Windows):

```
start myproject.sln
```

that would work from the hook as well.

Comment: ouch.. sorry.. similar stuff would work there I'm sure..